# UIPickerView text is not center aligned when I switch language RTL in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, locale, uipickerview, arabic-support

I am using the delegate method to set the title of `UIPickerView` and setting `.center` alignment. But if I switch from English to Arabic, it is right aligned. If the language is Arabic during launch, it left aligns after switching to English.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let title = getPickerViewTitle(for: row)
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 37))
    label.text = title
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return label
}
```

Comment: Are you reloading the view when the language changes?

Comment: Yes, the view get reloaded.

Comment: Try to use textAlignment as `natural` direction. Find more detail on -  https://useyourloaf.com/blog/natural-text-alignment-for-rtl-languages/

Comment: Giving alignment as `natural` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have using RTL Languages support with components then you need to update alignment forcefully.

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            var pickerLabel : UILabel
            if let label = view as? UILabel {
                pickerLabel = label
            } else {
                pickerLabel = UILabel()
                pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                if  pickerLabel.effectiveUserInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft {
                    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

                }
            }
            pickerLabel.text = "10"
            pickerLabel.sizeToFit()

            return pickerLabel
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

NO required to give UI lable frame try without this. Give constraint only you picker.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerLabel.text = "PickerView Cell Title"
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}
```

Comment: @jsloop please share screen shot. so I can understand what you want expertly.